# error while trying to restore a postgres db

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pg-restore

I'm trying to restore a table in a db in postgres from a .sql file.
I used command `pg_restore -d dbName file.sql`. The user is a superuser. But I got several errors:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC: 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 359; 1259 499945 TABLE fuller4t7 someName
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  permission denied to create "pg_catalog.fuller4t7"
DETAIL:  System catalog modifications are currently disallowed.
Command was: CREATE TABLE fuller4t7 (
             gid integer NOT NULL,
             geom public.geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)
);
```

Other errors are related with this one since the table was not created in the first place. I'm wondering what these errors mean. I'm using postgres 9.4 and I have PostGIS extensions added to the particular database.

Comment: What schema the table is in? Do you have this schema in `dbName` database?

Comment: @EgorRogov there are two schemas in `dbName`, public and topology, topology is created by PostGIS, I'm not sure what schemas are in the table to be restored, how could I find out?

Comment: `\d fuller4t7` in psql shows the schema name, and `\dn` shows all available schemas.

Comment: @EgorRogov I don't have access to the db that has table `fuller4t7`. All I have is a .sql that needs to be restored. In `dbName`, I have schemas `public` and `topology`

Comment: @EgorRogov in the second line of the error: `pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 359; 1259 499945 TABLE fuller4t7 someName`, `someName` is a person's name, but I think it's also the name of the db he created the .sql file from. This name is different from `dbName`